# Validation does not get called on PATCH

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have a serializer like

```
class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    age = serializers.HiddenField(default=None)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile

    def validate_age(self, value):
        # this code not executing in update(put/patch)
```

and view

```
class MyView(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin):

    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

When i `POST` the data `validate_age` get called, but not in the case of `PATCH`. Is it the intended behaviour or i am missing something ?

Comment: Please show your view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just posting some detail in case anyone is having similar issue. Digging  little bit deeper i found that my `HiddenField` was getting skipped [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3.2.4/rest_framework/fields.py#L452) because of empty value i think. `getattr(self.root, 'partial')` was returning True which is because of `PATCH`.

APIView call `partial_update` of `UpdateModelMixin` on `PATCH` which sets `partial` to True. Although in case of PUT `update`(not partial_update) method get called. So i just changed HTTP Method from `PATCH` to `PUT` and everything working fine.

However Now the question is why `HiddenField` is getting ignored on partial update. :)

Comment: I am having the same issue. Thanks for your Question&Answer. it works with `POST` as your discussion with Apoorv.

Answer (score -2):

According to django-rest docs:

> A [HiddenFiled] field class that does not take a value based on user input, but instead takes its value from a default value or callable.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#hiddenfield

As such, any user input for age will not actually run your specific validation code.

Another snippet:

> This field type does not accept user input, but instead always returns
>   it's default value to the validated_data in the serializer.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/

I would suggest using some sort of `IntegerField` or even `CharField` depending on your business logic.

Comment: I am not giving any user input. And however it is working fine with POST.

Comment: If no user input was given then i don't see how the custom specific validation code runs? Could you possibly output value in your validate_age validation code?

Comment: as i mentioned, its not getting called in ```PATCH```(Post is fine). I know that  user input have nothing to do with hidden field. drf3.2.4